# max pairs function standard ml

Tags: function, max, sml, ml

I'm trying to make a function in standard ml that takes a list of pairs of ints, and I should return a list of int that contains the max element from the pairs. `(int * int) list -> int list`. Now so far,I've written a code but it doesnt work and I cant seem to figure the problem from the error it gave.

Here's the code:

```
- fun maxpairs x = 
=   foldr (fn (a, b) => if a > b then a else b) [] x;
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
stdIn:15.2-15.50 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload]
  operator domain: 'Z
  operand:         'Y list
  in expression:
    (foldr (fn (<pat>,<pat>) => if <exp> then <exp> else <exp>)) nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foldr` takes a function of type `('a * 'b) -> 'b`, a value of type `'b` and a list of type `['a]`. In your case the list is a list of pairs and the value of type `'b` is an empty list. That means in the function `fn (a,b) => ...` `a` will be a pair and `b` will be a list. You then try to compare `a` and `b` using `>`. Since `>` can't be used with a pair as its left operand and a list as its right operand, that doesn't work. Also you can't have an if-statement where the then-expression and the else-expression have different types.

If I were you I'd use map for this, which seems to fit the problem better than using a fold.

Comment: Ohh okay, I see
It worked with the map function
Thanks very much sepp2k